# Does Future require to perform the computation in a separate thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, future

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

> Future represents the result of an asynchronous computation.

Does it mean that a thread calling the method [Future#get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) should not be a thread which performed the computation? So, is it appropriate if the thread calling [Future#get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) start the computation if it has not been yet? I'm not sure If I can call it asynchronous computation...

Comment: Your question is not very clear. But what would be the purpose of using a `Future` if you know that you only have one thread?

Comment: @SkinnyJ Not exactly one. I meant one thread calling the get method can start the computation, if necessary, so that other threads can use the future for getting result the thread's going to produce.

Comment: Calling `get()` will not "start computation". It just blocks the thread it is called on until the task has completed (on another thread). If it has completed before `get` is called, calling it will immediately return with the computed result. It's all in the JavaDoc.

Comment: @Fildor So, it means that the Future interface doesn't satisfied therequirements...?

Comment: Not solely by itself. You still need to execute the callable's task by using for example an ExecutorService.

Comment: @Fildor So, I will probably have to create my own interface representing such computation, right?

Comment: You can implement the callable interface, you even could do it in an anonymous class and submit it to an Executor. There are even convenience methods in [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) for creating suitable callables.

Comment: The ExecutorService has the [submit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)) method which then gives you the according Future. You can chose from a quite wide range of standard Executor implementations.

Comment: Actually, in the documentation of Future you linked to, there is an example on how to use all this right at the top of that page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term “asynchronous computation” does not mandate that the computation has to run in a different thread. If the API designers intended that, they had written “computation that runs in a different thread”. Here, it simply means that there is no specification about when the computation happens.

Likewise, the existing implementations provided by the JRE do not enforce a computation in a different thread. The probably most known implementation, `FutureTask` can be used as follows:

```
Callable<String> action = new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() {
        return "hello "+Thread.currentThread();
    }
};

FutureTask<String> ft=new FutureTask<>(action);
ft.run();
System.out.println(ft.get());
```

Normally, instances of `FutureTask` are created by an `ExecutorService` which will determine when and by which thread the computation will be executed:

```
ExecutorService runInPlace=new AbstractExecutorService() {
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        command.run();
    }
    public void shutdown() {}
    public List<Runnable> shutdownNow() { return Collections.emptyList(); }
    public boolean isShutdown() { return false; }
    public boolean isTerminated() { return false; }
    public boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) { return false; }
};
Future<String> f=runInPlace.submit(action);
System.out.println(ft.get());
```

Note that this `execute()` implementation does not violate [its contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute-java.lang.Runnable-):

> Executes the given command at some time in the future. The command may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, or in the calling thread, at the discretion of the Executor implementation.

Note the “or in the calling thread”…

Another implementation is the `ForkJoinTask`:

```
ForkJoinTask<String> fjt=new RecursiveTask<String>() {
    protected String compute() {
        return "hello "+Thread.currentThread();
    }
};
fjt.invoke();
System.out.println(fjt.get());
```

Note that, while this kind of task is intended to support splitting into subtasks, which can be executed by different threads, utilizing the calling thread is *intentional* here. If the task can’t be split, it runs entirely in the caller’s thread as that’s the most efficient solution.

---

These examples are all running in the caller thread, but none of them will execute the tasks within the `get()` method. In principle, that would not violate the contract as it returns the result value, when the computation has been performed, however, you are likely to have trouble when trying to implement the `get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` correctly. In contrast, having a non-working `cancel()` would be still within the contract.

Comment: Indeed, sounds very reasonble. Let me ask you one more question. As far as I got, the `FutureTask` instance that's produced by the submit method means that the task is already being executed, so the `get` method just requests the result, but not starts if it's not been yet. Now, I need to have some kind of "lazy" computation. Once we get an instance of an interface representing the computation it's not started untill a client call a method (call it `get`) requesting the result (or start computation, if neccesary). Is the `Future` interface still aproppriate in that case?

Comment: I think, there’s nothing wrong with that. The computation may start when the operating system’s scheduler assigns cpu time to a thread or when a work queue has been emptied up to the task or on an arbitrary trigger, which might be, when the first thread invokes `get`. The logic doesn’t change.

Answer (score 1):

A `Future.get()` can be done using the same thread that did the computation, but the net result is that nothing is done concurrently. It is demonstrated in the code below when the first executor is uncommented and the second one is commented out.

An extended [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) can be used (there are other options like the [`RejectedExecutionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionHandler.html)) to perform the computation using the current thread in case the computation (the `Callable` in the code below) cannot be done concurrently.

As to whether or not this is appropriate: in some special cases this might be needed but it is not how it is intended to be used. It looks like a premature optimization to me and I would only use it if I can see (measure) that the code that follows the intended usage does not provide the required performance AND the specialized/optimized code shows a significant performance improvement (and meets the required performance).

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class FutureGetSameThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Serial executor with a task-queue 
        // ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        // Serial executor without a task-queue 
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
        try {
            Callable<Integer> c = new Callable<Integer>() {
                @Override 
                public Integer call() throws Exception {
                    Thread.sleep(400L); // pretend to be busy
                    return 1;
                }
            };
            final Future<Integer> f = executor.submit(c);
            Callable<Integer> c2 = new Callable<Integer>() {
                @Override 
                public Integer call() throws Exception {
                    // wait for the result from the previous callable and add 1
                    return f.get() + 1;
                }
            };
            Future<Integer> f2 = null;
            try {
                f2 = executor.submit(c2);
                System.out.println("Second callable accepted by executor with task queue.");
            } catch (RejectedExecutionException ree) {
                System.out.println("Second callable rejected by executor without task queue.");
                f2 = new FutureTaskUsingCurrentThread<Integer>(c2);
            }
            Integer result = f2.get();
            System.out.println("Result: " + result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
    }

    static class FutureTaskUsingCurrentThread<V> extends FutureTask<V> {

        public FutureTaskUsingCurrentThread(Callable<V> callable) {
            super(callable);
        }

        @Override
        public V get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
            run();
            return super.get();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, `java.util.concurrent.Future` is only an `interface`.

It's a place holder for a value that might not be immediately available.  A method that has access to a Future can:

- Test whether the value is available,
- get the value, or
- "cancel" the future.

According to the API contract, the `future.get()` operation is allowed to block the caller until the value becomes available.

The API contract does *not* say where the value came from, or why it might not be available, or what mechanism might block the caller of the `get()` method; and while it says how "cancel" should *appear* to behave, it doesn't say anything about what "cancel" actually should do.  That's all implementation dependent.

`Future` was intended to be returned by `executorService.submit(callable)`.

If your method obtains a Future from one of the built-in `ExecutorService` implementations, then when you call `future.get()`, you will in fact be waiting for another thread to produce the result.

Comment: You're right, yes, but `Future` represents asynchronous computation, that's why I would say that the actual computation must be performed in another thread...

Comment: @St.Antario, perhaps it depends on what you mean by `Future`.  Are you talking about the interface,  `java.util.concurrent.Future`?  Or are you talking about an instance of some class that _implements_ `Future`, and which was returned by a call to some particular library method?  If you really are talking about the interface, then there is very little that anyone can say about what it _must_ do.  If, on the other hand, you are talking about the Futures that are returned by some particular method, then the answer to your question might depend on _what_ method.